# Why is the CQRS repository publishing events, not the event store?

Tags: cqrs

According to http://cre8ivethought.com/blog/2009/11/12/cqrs--la-greg-young the component responsible for publishing events using an event publisher is the repository.

My question simply is: Why is that?

In this blog post we are told that:

> The domain repository is responsible for publishing the events, this would normally be inside a single transaction together with storing the events in the event store.

I would have expected this as a task of the event store: Once an event (or multiple events) has been stored, it's published.

So why is it on the repository?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your domain model is unaware of the storing mechanism. On the other hand it must make sure that the appropriate events will be published, no matter if you use an event store, a classical SQL store, or any other means of persistence.

If you rely on the event store to publish the events you'd have a tight coupling to the storage mechanism.

Comment: Because the storing of the event and the publishing of that event needs to be atomic operation while still avoiding 2PC, and as you mentioned, the publishing of those events shouldn't be the responsibility of the underlying eventstore, is the solution to rather use a DB table to store the event while setting a "not published" marker. Have another process read the events marked "not published" from that table and then publish them, after which the marker is set and the transaction committed? If this is the case, is polling that table for unpublished events the way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Storing and publishing the event must an atomic instruction because if one of both actions fails, the listeners of this event will be out of sync with the producer of the event.

There is a another (more expensive) solution, compared to publishing the event from the event store, which is to use 2pc transactions (two-phases commit).

you can find some more intereting information here: https://cqrs.wordpress.com/documents/building-event-storage/